# Get ongoing events in EF core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

I have some events in a database for my event registrations application, where the dates may be set by

```
public DateTime? DateStart { get; set; }
public DateTime? DateEnd { get; set; }
```

Both fields are nullable, and I want to get ongoing events if eiter
1) DateStart is same date as today, or
2) Now is between DateStart and DateEnd

```
public async Task<List<EventInfo>> GetOngoingEventsAsync() 
{
    return await _db.EventInfos
        .Where(i => 
            i.Published && 
            i.DateStart.Value.Date == DateTime.Now.Date ||
            i.DateStart.Value.Date <= DateTime.Now.Date <= i.DateEnd.Value.Date)
        .OrderBy(s => s.DateStart)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

However my code above returns: `Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'DateTime'`

Comment: Have you tried `(DateTime.Now.Date >= i.DateStart.Value.Date && DateTime.Now.Date <= i.DateEnd.Value.Date)`?

Comment: @Ali Thanks, so easy. Please add as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind the error was the first part of the condition `i.DateStart.Value.Date <= DateTime.Now.Date` will be validated and will be converted to `Boolean`. After that you were trying to compare `Boolean` with `DateTime` like so `<= i.DateEnd.Value.Date`. So that's why I separate the two conditions with `&&` operator.

`(DateTime.Now.Date >= i.DateStart.Value.Date && DateTime.Now.Date <= i.DateEnd.Value.Date)`

Answer (score 0):

This should be the correct form of your code:

```
(DateTime.Now.Date >= i.DateStart.Value.Date && DateTime.Now.Date <= i.DateEnd.Value.Date)
```